# Jqgrid virtual Paging

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

Is there any example showing how to do virtual paging?

I want to load 25 records on page load, then load the other 25 records on top of the existing 25 when the user clicks on the pager or on next button so it will go back to the server and bring 50 records( the first 25 plus the next 25).

Comment: can't find a example for a click and search, but there is an example that loads data on scroll. see http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html "New in version 3.4 -> Autoloading data when scroll"

Answer (score 1):

See [demos](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html), section "New in version 3.7" -> Virtual scrolling